# Prometheus how "up" metrics works

Tags: prometheus

I'm looking for information how "up" metrics is calculated by Prometheus

```
up{job="<job-name>", instance="<instance-id>"}: 1 if the instance is healthy, i.e. reachable, or 0 if the scrape failed.
```

How Prometheus calculate when

> the instance is healthy

I'm using Apache Cassandra with Prometheus and from time to time "up" metrics showing "down". However Cassandra working OK.

Answer (score 19):

Prometheus automatically adds `up` metric alongside a few other metrics (such as `scrape_duration_seconds`, `scrape_samples_scraped`, `scrape_series_added`, etc.) when scraping metrics from each configured scrape target - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) for more details. The `up` metric is set to `1` per each successful scrape. It is set to `0` otherwise. The `up` metric can be set to `0` in the following cases:

- When scrape target was unreachable during the scrape.
- When the target didn't return response during the configured timeout. The timeout can be configured via `scrape_timeout` option. By default it is set to 10 seconds. See more details about this option [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config).
- When there was a network issue during the scrape, which prevented from successful scrape.
- When the scrape target returns incorrect or incomplete response. The response must contain metrics with values in [Prometheus text exposition format](https://github.com/Showmax/prometheus-docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md#text-format-details).

There may be other reasons for failed scrape. The last reason for failed scrape can be inspected at `http://prometheus-host:9090/targets` page in the `error` column. See, for example, http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/targets .

Answer (score 16):

From [the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/):

> `up{job="<job-name>", instance="<instance-id>"}`: `1` if the instance is healthy, i.e. reachable, or `0` if the scrape failed.

i.e. it is a per scraper / exporter metric which means whether the exporter was available / reachable or not.

Comment: hmm, you copy and paste exactly what I pasted from docs. Thanks. However my question is still unanswered: how scraper calculate that instance is "up"

Comment: it's not a calculation, if the scrape succeeded it is up=1 if it failed (e.g. 4xx, 5xx, timeout, unreachable, unroutable) it is up=0

Comment: do you know where I can find logic of scrape responsible for "up/down" metrics? Cassandra is noSQL database, I do not understand from where prometheus get this 4xx, 5xx or timeout values. How they know what to check

Comment: prom scrapes what you tell it to scrape (port and targets in the discovery config) what it hits depends on the exporter you setup in cass